# How to remove every {element} after the 3rd one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a list of objects that I need to trim down on special occasions using jQuery. For intents and purposes, let's say it looks like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="child one">stuff</div>
    <div class="child two">stuff</div>
    <div class="child three">stuff</div>
    <div class="child four">stuff</div>
    <div class="child five">stuff</div>
</div>
```

Is there a simple way (with jQuery, pure JS if necessary I suppose) to remove 'every' `.child` after the third one?

Note: the `.one, .two .three` is not necessarily in numerical order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, using the [`:gt` selector](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/):

```
$("#container > .child:gt(2)").remove();
```

...which means "select all `.child` elements that are immediate children of `#container` and are at index 2 or higher (indexes start at 0).

Or if you don't like using jQuery's extended selectors (because they can't be passed through to the browser's own selector engine), you can use [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter the children:

```
$("#container > .child").filter(function(index) {
    return index > 2;
}).remove();
```

If they're the *only* children, you can use `.children` instead of the `> .child` part of that selector:

```
$("#container").children().filter(function(index) {
    return index > 2;
}).remove();
```

Comment: You could also use `$("#container > :nth-child(n+4)").remove();` -- pretty much the same as your own answer however :)

Comment: @pebbl - thanks! But for some reason I don't like using `:nth-child` selectors. Pre-JS issues with that I suppose? Haha

@T.J Crowder - Thanks! I don't mind jQuery's extended selectors (I actually prefer them over using `.filter`. Thanks for this, works' great :) (Will accept when it let's me :))

Answer (score 1):

Use :gt() selector and .remove()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#container .child:gt(2)').remove();
});
```

[DEMO VIEW](http://jsfiddle.net/teShe/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.child').gt(2).remove();
```

here gt means greaterthan

Comment: I don't think there's a `.gt` function (anymore).

Comment: However there is a `.slice` method that will do the same in this case: `$(".child").slice(2).remove();` *"Reduce the set of matched elements to a subset specified by a range of indices"*